# android SDK maps gives the wrong user location

Tags: android

I need to get the user location in android but i get the wrong location, I am in London and the location i see in the emulator is US. I created an API key and followed the steps from the following link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#the_maps_activity_java_file
but i still have the same problem, the wrong latitude and longitude. Can anyone help on this please?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you pls check your emulator's GPS location- latitude and longitude.

Comment: I tried to display this in the emaulator but nothing is diplayed there!

Comment: I found this 37.4945, -122.0746 on the emulator

Comment: Can you pls run with your real device.

Answer (score 0):

In emulator change lat and lan.  Inside location

Comment: The solution was to run the application on a phone instead of a virtual emulator.